# Docker use local db for volume

Tags: php, mysql, magento, docker

I am new to Docker. I am trying to use docker to install Magento2 using an existing setup I already have working locally. My web is in ./ and my database is located in /var/lib/mysql. When I do docker-compose up -d my mysql container eventually stops working and the containers are not linking to the db. I have no idea why it is not working or linking.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
     - ./:/var/www/html
    links:
      - db
    env_file:
      - env
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.18
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - env
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alexcheng/apache2-php7

MAINTAINER Fu Cheng <alexcheng1982@gmail.com>

RUN a2enmod rewrite

ENV MAGENTO_VERSION 2.1.6

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN requirements="libpng12-dev libmcrypt-dev libmcrypt4 libcurl3-dev libfreetype6 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg-turbo8-dev libpng12-dev libfreetype6-dev libicu-dev libxslt1-dev" \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y $requirements && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-install mbstring \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install xsl \
    && docker-php-ext-install soap \
    && requirementsToRemove="libpng12-dev libmcrypt-dev libcurl3-dev libpng12-dev libfreetype6-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev" \
    && apt-get purge --auto-remove -y $requirementsToRemove

COPY ./auth.json /var/www/.composer/
COPY ./ /var/www/html/
RUN chsh -s /bin/bash www-data
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
RUN su www-data -c "cd /var/www/html \
    && find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \; \
    && find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \; \
    && chmod u+x bin/magento"

COPY ./bin/install-magento /usr/local/bin/install-magento
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-magento

RUN echo "memory_limit=1024M" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memory-limit.ini

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

WORKDIR /var/www/html

VOLUME /var/www/html/var
VOLUME /var/www/html/pub

# Add cron job
ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/magento2-cron
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/magento2-cron
RUN crontab -u www-data /etc/cron.d/magento2-cron
```

env:

```
MYSQL_HOST=db
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypass
MYSQL_USER=myuser
MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypass
MYSQL_DATABASE=mydbname

MAGENTO_LANGUAGE=en_US
MAGENTO_TIMEZONE=America/New_York
MAGENTO_DEFAULT_CURRENCY=USD
MAGENTO_URL=http://<ip of vm>

MAGENTO_ADMIN_FIRSTNAME=admin
MAGENTO_ADMIN_LASTNAME=store
MAGENTO_ADMIN_EMAIL=my@email.com
MAGENTO_ADMIN_USERNAME=admin
MAGENTO_ADMIN_PASSWORD=mypass
```

docker log db

```
  2017-05-18T19:14:40.184335Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.18) starting as process 1 ...
2017-05-18T19:14:40.200332Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2017-05-18T19:14:40.200675Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-05-18T19:14:40.200776Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-05-18T19:14:40.200846Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2017-05-18T19:14:40.200873Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2017-05-18T19:14:40.200917Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-05-18T19:14:40.206612Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-05-18T19:14:40.208420Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-05-18T19:14:40.217005Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2017-05-18T19:14:40.223891Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: mmap(137428992 bytes) failed; errno 12
2017-05-18T19:14:40.224185Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2017-05-18T19:14:40.224254Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2017-05-18T19:14:40.224324Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2017-05-18T19:14:40.224352Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-05-18T19:14:40.224398Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2017-05-18T19:14:40.224420Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2017-05-18T19:14:40.224455Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2017-05-18T19:14:40.225243Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2017-05-18T19:14:40.225843Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2017-05-18T19:14:40.226701Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: Have you checked the log files?

Comment: "my mysql container eventually stops working" - what does this mean? Can you provide the logs for the containers? What local version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: I added the log of docker db container. The container starts then when I go to the home page I get a blank screen and when I run docker ps the db container is no longer running.

Answer (score 0):

Docker was using all the memory had to purchase a bigger droplet